# Method cannot be applied to ArrayList<ObjectImplementsInterface> if definited for ArrayList<Interface>

Tags: java, android

I have various Objects named `Gold`,`Iron` etc. all these objects implement the interface `Metal`.
Since I have to do same kind of operations on all these Objects i have definited my method to accept `ArrayList<Metal>`to avoid redundant code.

for example

```
public ArrayList<Metal> doSomething(ArrayList<Metal> list){
...
}
```

but if try to do something like

```
ArrayList<Iron> inputList;
ArrayList<Iron> result=doSomething(inputList);
```

I get the error: `doSomething` *cannot be applied to* `ArrayList<Iron>`

How could I fix this without write redundant methods that do the same thing for each Object type?

EDIT

A sample of method edited according user suggestions is this

```
public static <T extends Metal> List<T>  addMoleculaInMetalList(ArrayList<? extends Metal> list, Molecula t) {
        Metal ma;
        ArrayList<Molecula> moleculist;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            ma = list.get(i);
            if (ma.getName().equals(t.getDestinationName())) {
                moleculist = ma.getMoleculas();
                moleculist.add(t);
                ma.setMoleculas(moleculist);
                list.set(i, ma);
                return list;
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

but doesn't work, get

-error cannot be applied in

```
 list.set(i, ma);
```

and 
-error *incompatible types* on `return`

Comment: that kind of depends on what `doSomething` actually does. Does it modify the list? does it create new elements? where do the returned elements come from? are they created, or are they part of `list`?

Comment: You shouldn't have tried to mix both answers together.  Pick one or the other.  Either one of them will work.  But you do have to change the type of `ma`.  See my comment under one of the answers (and I realised after commenting that Mike had made the same comment under the other).

Comment: I have already tried to not mix answers, I have tried `public List<Metal> doSomething(List<? extends Metal> list)` and same 2 errors, I have tried `public <T extends Metal> List<T> doSomething(List<T> list)`, same errors. if I change the type of ma to `T` I cannot use the methods of interface `Metal`, so cannot work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `ArrayList<Iron>` is not an `ArrayList<Metal>` even though an `Iron` is a `Metal`. Change your method signature to:

```
public List<Metal> doSomething(List<? extends Metal> list)
```

It's better to use the interface `List` as the parameter and return type rather than the concrete `ArrayList`. If you decide to use a `LinkedList` in the future you won't need to change your method signature.

Is there a reason you need to get an `List<Iron>` rather than an `List<Metal>` back when you pass in an `ArrayList<Iron>`?

If not, then call the method like

```
List<Metal> result = doSomething(inputList);
```

If so, then you'll need to make the method signature like

```
public <T extends Metal> List<T> doSomething(List<T> list)
```

Now when you call it, the parameter and return type must match.

Comment: thanks but in this way I get error cannot be applied on all lines  `list.set(i, myInterfaceObject);`that i use to replace object in list, and still same error on doSomething

Comment: I edited to add more. If you have questions about other parts of your code such as where you call `list.set()` then you'll have to post the relevant code to get an answer.

Comment: it's more that a `List<Metal>` is not a `List<Iron>`

Comment: your last line is wrong. you could call your method with a list of anything that is a metal and still receive a list of Iron or Gold depending on the receiver. `Then when you call it passing in a List<Iron> the return type will be List<Iron>`. No. the return type will be the type inferred from the left side operand.

Comment: @AndreaF Change the first line of your `addMoleculaInMetalList` method from `Metal ma;` to `T ma;`

Comment: @AndreaF Also update your method signature to match what I edited mine to be or what njzk2 has in his answer.

Comment: I get the same error cannot be applied on `list.set(i, ma);`

Answer (score 1):

Change your method signature to

```
public <T extends Metal> List<T> doSomething(List<T> list)
```

This way you have a method that takes a list of `<T extends Metal>`, and returns a list of the same things (`T`).

Comment: As well as doing this, you have to change the first line of the method to `T ma;`

Comment: But this make no sense, since If I do `T ma` I cannot use any of methods of the interface `Metal` on `ma`so the code will not work

Comment: yes you can. T is defined as `extends Metal` therefore you can call any method of metal on it

Comment: Yes, you can.  You declared that `T` extends `Metal`, which means that `T` is any subtype of `Metal`, and you can call any of `Metal`'s methods on `T`.  Please try it, rather than just asserting that it can't work.

Comment: @DavidWallace
tried, yes seems that can use Metal methods but get the same error  cannot be applied at the line `list.set(i, ma);`